# Connect MBP Late 2014 to Samsung LC49J890

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have some doubts about how to connect my MacBook Pro 2014 to this Samsung monitor to get the resolution of 3840x1080.

The problem comes with the use of a docking station, therefore I will not use the HDMI, I will not be able to use the DP since it will be connected to another computer.  So I would like to know if there is any way to connect using TB2 for maximum resolution, I have tried with an mDP to HDMI adapter and I can not upload 1080p, I have seen that there is an official Apple cable from type-C to TB2 but I do not know if this will work. I would like to know what solution I can have with the available inputs.

[image]
[image]